# How to keep al external jar and class inside that jar in proguard

Tags: android, proguard

I have a android project which has many external jar reference.These jars are in libs folder so they get included but on launching app my  application crashes on refering methods or fields of class(in external jar).To avoid this I write -keep class ******** and then it works.
But as I have many jars so writing -keep for all is quite hectic.

I would also like to remove all the logs including verbose and all.Normal log have been removed by

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log { 
   *; 
}

but still other logs like mediaplayer and setting and all coming.

is there any way around to this in proguard? How can i tell proguard to keep external jar with all the class and fields.?

Answer (score 0):

Try insert

```
-libraryjars libs/android-support-v4.jar
```

and all libraries in file proguard.cfg